# Permalinks in Wordpress not working

Tags: php, wordpress, permalinks

Recently I have updated PHP from version 5.3 to 5.5 on my web server.

Wordpress Permalinks was working prior to that, but now Permalinks has stopped working, and I have to use the default option which gives the page id in url.

Wordpress version is 4.0.1

Comment: Are you sure your .htaccess file is still there?

Comment: Yes .htaccess file is still there and with the following content                                                   
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to admin
2. Click Settings
3. Click Permalinks
4. Select Post Name (for clean permalinks) or default
5. Finally Click Save

This rewrites .htaccess and wordpress permalinks may work in most cases

if .htaccess is not created, make .htaccess with following

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

can you also confirm mod_rewrite is enabled in your server?

Comment: It does not rewrites on .htaccess file

Comment: if so please delete .htaccess from ftp manager. then default permalink structure works, otherwise, please explain what error is comming when you open link, so that i can investigate the problem

Comment: delete .htaccess did not help. Permalink still not working. "Error is 404 page not found" while using permalinks

Comment: This error normally occurs due to htaccess or if site url is changed but database not fixed for new permalinks or if page has form control with same name like post type,  category slug etc. Can you go to wp_posts table and see guid for certain post? Use that url? For testing?

Comment: In the table wp_posts under column GUID i see URL with page_id. Is that what I should be looking at.? Or I guess, it should be the permalink address.?

Comment: Yes guid is the actual address of post...check page with that and report me back so that we can find solution

Comment: Yes the link opens with that address www.mywebsite.com/?page_id=1556 but previously it opened at www.mywebsite.com/contactus

Comment: then, follow my steps above, and in step 4, select postname option and click save, the verify if .htaccess is generated or not, if htaccess generates then it should work..

Comment: it does not rewrites .htaccess file, I have checked the permissions of that file too it is writable file.

Comment: now I have updated .htaccess code to my answer, copy that code and create .htaccess file with that in your wordpress root

Comment: Still give the error The requested URL /partners/ was not found on this server. Copy Pasted the code you have modified.

Comment: Yes mod_rewrite is enabled, i can see it in phpinfo.php

Comment: Thanks Sagar, Resolved it, <Directory "/var/www/html"> AllowOverride All was None before, sorry for the trouble

Comment: I would, If i could, I am on 11 Points need 15+ for that.

Answer (score 1):

For some situations just resaving the permalink settings in `Dashboard>Settings>Permalink>[postname]>Save Changes` will refresh the `.htaccess` file.

If that is ignored, chances are that the `.htaccess` file is not writeable. In that case, check your `apache.conf`:

```
sudo vi /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride ALL <----(edit from none)
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Then restart apache2 using:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

While there, be sure to double-check permissions and owner of the file:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data  1668 Jan  8 04:34 .htaccess
```